# Python Selenium Webdriver Stopped Working for Firefox (Inexplicably)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

I am running Python 3.5.0 and Selenium 2.53.6. I had a functioning web scraper that would navigate using Firefox, however it all of a sudden stopped working. I do admit computers don't just change their behavior for no reason, but I can't figure out what has changed and that's why I'm here to ask for help :)

The problem is, the Firefox window will successfully open, but it appears the communication between it and the webdriver is incomplete in some form. It's as if the webdriver is waiting for some "Okay, I've loaded." message from Firefox but it's not getting it. The reason I say that is I have stepped through this in IDLE and when I execute `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`, the browser window opens but a new line (>>>) never appears. If I wait for about a minute, I get the timeout (I think) error below. I see the bit about loading a profile but I haven't changed anything that I can think of that would have caused the change in functionality.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
         driver = webdriver.Firefox()
       File "C:\Users\Dane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
 line 77, in __init__
         self.binary, timeout),
       File "C:\Users\Dane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py",
 line 49, in __init__
         self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
       File "C:\Users\Dane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
 line 68, in launch_browser
         self._wait_until_connectable()
       File "C:\Users\Dane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
 line 103, in _wait_until_connectable
         raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
     selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the
 FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I had initially thought it would be due to a `Firefox` update, but I checked the update log and my scraper worked for 4 weeks after the latest update. I'm running **Firefox 46.0.1**. Thank you for any help you're able to provide.

Comment: I would still strongly recommend downgrading FF version. I would not generally go above FF 43. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: I had considered that, however I worry about security exploits. If that's the only way, I'll do it, but I would prefer to not go that route. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Please, when Firefox comes open, check that WebDriver plugin is installed in the plugins. Also, check firewall, better to just turn it off

Comment: Is a plugin really necessary? To my knowledge, I didn't have one installed before, and from what I can tell on seleniumhq.org (is this the official Selenium site?), there are no Firefox plugins directly from them, only third party options.